# Shallow rooted yew trees

Tags: trees

Are there are species of yew trees that are shallow rooted as when we have searched the classification it comes up deep rooted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You want shallow-rooted evergreens? Azalea.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to find out the correct classification for yew trees , deep rooted or shallow rooted .

Answer (score 0):

I have planted yew trees from seed and from nursery stock.

When I planted them from seed and tried to move them ten years later the root was thicker than my arm and went down very deeply through solid clay. That didn't work.

Nursery stock will have a more diverse root system but if it has been planted for a while it will develop a central root that goes deep.

Keep in mind that even though yews are planted as shrubs in the right conditions they are [very long lived trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxus)